# can't find the wrong in python bot

Tags: python, bots

I was making a bot for dino chrome that jumps, but I think I am not getting the true value of color. If you want information tell me.

The code is here:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageOps
import pyautogui
import time
from numpy import *


class Cordinates():
    replayBtn = (370, 405)
    dinasur = (165, 512)

    def restartGame():
        pyautogui.click(Cordinates.replayBtn)

    def pressSpace():
        pyautogui.keyDown('space')
        time.sleep(0.05)
        pyautogui.keyUp('space')

    def thebox():
        box = (157, 416, 201, 432)
        image = ImageGrab.grab(box)
        grayImage = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
        a = array(grayImage.getcolors())
        print(a.sum())

    def main():
        restartGame()
        while True:
            if thebox() != 951:
                pressSpace()
                time.sleep(.1)

main()
```

Comment: You might want to add some punctuation marks in your question. At the moment it's nearly unreadable (at least for a not native english speaker).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us **what** is your expected result.

Comment: You're defining a class and then calling methods of that class without first creating an instance of that class! No wonder it doesn't work. Your ambition is commendable, but my advice would be to get some basic instructions in the language first - follow one of the many excellent online introductory tutorials on Python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value from thebox() so that it can be used in the comparison of main()

```
   def thebox():
        box = (157, 416, 201, 432)
        image = ImageGrab.grab(box)
        grayImage = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
        a = array(grayImage.getcolors())
        return a.sum()


    def main():
        restartGame()
        while True:
            if thebox() != 951:
                pressSpace()
                time.sleep(.1)
```